# Why would a hosting company not provide ImageMagick on a shared server?

Tags: 4.7, hosting, mosaico

My hosting company (vidahost.com) have always been good about providing a Civi friendly environment for a reasonable cost & performance.  However having moved some domains to a different server (to avoid a problem - see [this problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21004/why-do-i-get-security-warning-how-to-remove)) they now tell me that ImageMagick is now not available on their shared servers. This is a real problem as one client has developed some great e-newsletterws using the Mosaico extension.  I'm puzzled why this should be the case - except perhaps to force people to a more expensive VPS solution.  Are there other reasons why ImageMagick should be excluded from a shared server?

Comment: This is a question about server administration, not about CiviCRM per se. At some point, every hosting company has to decide what packages it will include and which ones it won't. PHP already comes with gd, so why add another finicky, CPU-intensive package to support on top of it?

Comment: Not strictly about server admin, because the Mosaico extension, very widely used (#3 on stats.civicrm.org extensions) depends on ImageMagick.  So of interest to the Civi community.

Comment: It's very much of interest to those using commodity hosting.  It might be worth explaining to them that Mosaico is a popular CiviCRM extension and likely to become the default so not providing it means they will lose CiviCRM customers.  On the other hand, I'd recommend specialist CiviCRM hosting anyway.

Comment: I asked Vidahost the same thing and was told that I needed a VPS which would cost our small not-for-profit the same per month as our annual hosting currently does :-( It's a shame, but I can understand their logic as @choster has already mentioned. My main gripe, however, is not with Vidahost but with Mosaico for making ImageMagick a requirement. It would be great to see its image-manipulation code become library-agnostic.

Comment: Vidahost has come back and said that the ImageMagick binaries are installed on the shared servers, and I've seen that scenario mentioned on a2hosting's website.  I don't know what this means, frankly - does it mean Civi can access it or is there something else that's required?

Comment: The presence of the binaries isn't the issue. It needs to be made available to PHP - which it isn't on my Vidahost shared servers. I hope you can persuade them to enable it :)

Comment: The same problem with sohosted. They don't allow imagemagick for technical reasons. So, the only solution is to migrate everything?

Comment: Hey Dirk, I saw you're a new user and wanted to give you some feedback as you've posted your question as an answer. Instead, it'd be better as a comment on the original post.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7214)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7214)

Answer (score 1):

I use Stablehost's shared server services and have access to all PHP options including ImageMagick.  Some hosts choose to restrict access to these functions in order to reduce the number of "complex" websites on their server so they can cram more websites on their server. Most reputable shared hosts provide resource usage limits that they define as acceptable for their service.  Restricting what libraries you can use is a poor business choice.

While this isn't a CiviCRM question - I think questions around webhosts and what they offer are important. I hope you get VidaHost to enable it for you - if they don't - take your business elsewhere.

Comment: After going backwards and forwards with Vidahost I wrote a complaint. But they are saying that users can only have what is available via cPanel. So I am looking for a new hosting company. And ImageMagick is a prerequisite of Mosaico so can't blame the extension writers!

Comment: My host uses Cpanel - I have ImageMagick as well as a host of other options - so I am calling out their BS. @AndyClark good luck.  Check out my host (StableHost) or another host I have used and I am considering returning to that is a CiviCRM sustainer (TMDHosting).

Comment: I moved to Civihosting, by the way